# What stylesheets are available in core?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I would like to use the jQuery UI style [Sheet](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css), but I don't know whether it's pre-installed in WordPress or not.

Without knowing that I think it could create a problem. If it is available in WordPress, in that case `wp_register_style()` will become problematic because first we have to `wp_deregister_style( $handle )` and then register our script, otherwise the two stylesheets may conflict.

Even if I'm asking a wrong question just give me some idea or resources where I can find available scripts and styles, so that I can easily find out what are the styles and script I need to register and enqueue in my plugin.

One more thing I don't have to do useless code like registering a stylesheet if it is already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WordPress pre-installed style sheets can be found at:

- `../wp-admin/css/` - for stylesheets used in the admin
- `../wp-includes/css/` - for all other stylesheets which may also be used in the admin.

As you can see the stylesheets which are available on the front-end are minimal, focussing mainly on:

- admin-bar
- TinyMCE editor (which is available on the front-end)
- dialog & log-in dialogs (I believe used when the user is logged-in and their cookies expire).
- buttons (used on the log-in page).
- pointers (new feature pointers, again only for logged-in users).

This is intentional because its the *theme* that should be providing the styling for the front-end (not WordPress, and not plug-ins). As for where themes store their stylesheets... well that could be pretty much anywhere :), but any half-decent theme will have an appropriate directory structure.

To answer your question, no WordPress does not come with a jQuery UI stylesheet (not even for the admin). See tract ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18909

Comment: Thanks for extra information on why WordPress focusing more on admin Intentionally.